# Public and Private Keys are Incorrect for user

Tags: ssh

For some time, I'm getting the error `Public and Private keys incorrect for wp-user` when I try to update a plug-in.

I've a CentOS 7 VPS setup with a LAMP stack. I've installed and configured my Wordpress installation which works fine except that I can't update plug-ins or make image uploads via the Wordpress control panel.

I let Wordpress access to my server using SSH. I've followed [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-secure-updates-and-installations-in-wordpress-on-ubuntu?comment=28021) to do so. Basically there is a specific user in my system created for this task(making Wordpress connect via SSH) and it has the SSH keys. According to the tutorial, the permissions of various files are all okay(I've double-checked) but nevertheless Wordpress does not perform the operation.

What other configuration do I need?

Some other information:

- the user for the Wordpress SSH operation has a password so it can log-in via Ssh and it's specifically allowed in `ssh_config`

Comment: Have you tried to create new keys?

Comment: @Eduart I just tried that and the error is the same. Any other ideas?

Comment: How do you access your server, with ssh key? If not, can you try to create a pair of keys and use them to access your server or for any other thing, just to be sure if it is wordpress fault or server fault.

Comment: @Eduart I access my server via SSH through keys.

Comment: I tried do reproduce the error on localhost and i got  this error only before adding wp-user to owner group which in my case is my name `Public and Private keys incorrect for wp-user`. So what i think is that the error you are getting is caused by some permission settings.

Comment: @Eduart my user for this operation is 'wp-user'. The SSH keys are under '.ssh' folder under that user(/home/wp-user/.ssh). They're both owned by 'wp-user:apache'. The 'authorized_keys' file is owned by 'wp-user:wp-user'. All three have 644. What exactly did you change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it! Finally after a lot of frustrating days.

In the tutorial page, deep down in the comments, someone suggested removing/commenting the following line:

define('FTP_PRIKEY','/home/wp-user/');

I did this and immediately the error message disappeared and things started getting updated.

Comment: Well, it's good it worked for you, but this seems like a long shot. You *do* need a private key for SSH to work. Perhaps there was a key in the .ssh directory for wp-user, and after you commented the line out, that was used.

Comment: But wp-user should not have shell access and therefore shouldn't have a home directory. Better to explicitly specify where the public and private keys are.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message.

In my case I had created the ssh key with a passphrase. But [the codex site](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Enabling_SSH_Upgrade_Access) says "It is recommended to use a private key that is not pass-phrase protected. There have been numerous reports that pass phrase protected private keys do not work properly."

It worked once I recreated they key without a passphrase.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old topic, but I was never able to find the answer that worked for us anywhere.

The root cause for us was a library does not work with OpenSSH RSA keys. I don't know exactly which has the issue; we were using Ubuntu 20.04's packages of libssh2 and php7.4-ssh2. This seems to have been an issue since PHP 5 days and is still ongoing in 2021.

You can easily test if your private RSA key is an OpenSSH RSA key if it starts with the following line:

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Unfortunately, that's the default output when running `ssh-keygen` on many popular web servers.

If it starts with the following, it *should* work assuming everything else is set up properly:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

That type of key can be created by running `ssh-keygen -m PEM -t rsa`. It also seemed that other key types worked, too.

If you aren't using an OpenSSH-format RSA key, I'd suggest checking the system auth logs (for example, `/var/log/auth.log`). Also, try SSH-ing as the user you're trying (for example, `sudo -u www-data ssh ubuntu@localhost -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa`). Any error messages provided by those should be much more helpful than the one encountered here.

Note, incorrect file permissions can also result in this same error message. We kept all website files owned by the SFTP user so the web server cannot write any files except through SFTP. We set the access keys are owned by `root:www-data` so both the SSH user and web server—both members of the `www-data` group—could use the keys.

Lastly, make sure the keys are in the authorized keys file (`~/.ssh/authorized_keys`).

Good luck to anyone that comes across this!

Answer (score 0):

[blakek](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/397774) set me on the right path, but ultimately neither OPENSSH or RSA worked for me. I had to create an `ecdsa` key:

```
ssh-keygen -t ecdsa
```

Definitely check the auth log (`/var/log/auth.log` in Ubuntu) to see any related error messages. The error I was getting was:

```
userauth_pubkey: key type ssh-rsa not in PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms [preauth]
```

Hope this saves someone a few hours debugging!