# Public and Private keys incorrect for user

Tags: permissions, ssh

I am attempting to set up a WordPress installation on a DigitalOcean Ubuntu droplet, however after following the instructions on

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-secure-updates-and-installations-in-wordpress-on-ubuntu

I get "Public and Private keys incorrect for user", I have followed the instructions to the word but still no luck installing a theme.

I found this question ([Public and Private Keys are Incorrect for user](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/194529/public-and-private-keys-are-incorrect-for-user)) which was asked but the answer doesn't solve my issue, I don't have enough rep to comment to further help so I'm raising this question.

I have created the user wp-user, the authorized_keys file is in the /home/wp-user/.ssh directory which is owned by 'wp-user:wp-user' with 700 permissions. The 'authorized_keys' file is owned by 'wp-user:wp-user' with 644 permissions.

The wp_rsa and wp_rsa.pub files are in the /home/wp-user directory with is owned by 'wp-user:wp-user' with 755 permissions.

The wp_rsa file is owned by 'wp-user:www-data' with 600 permissions and the wp_rsa.pub is owned by 'wp-user:www-data' with 644 permissions.

I believe this issue maybe a permissions issue but I'm not sure what I've done wrong. Please let me know what I need to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I contacted DigitalOcean who told me to do the following which solved my issue:

> We recommend removing the changes you made to
>   wp-config.php to start. Once done, please try issuing this command: 
>   sudo chown -R www-data:www-data wordpress
>
> Just change 'wordpress' to the directory of WordPress installation,
>   and see if that works to waive the FTP credential requirement. :)